# openGL: cant move along x or y axis and negative scaling culls the wrong faces

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

So I've implemented a movable camera using all the projection maths and things. I have some input conditions, when I hit A or D I'm meant to move left and right respectively, but I cant do that, the camera only moves on the Z axis. Not only that but when I scale by a negative number on any axis the cube I'm rendering is inverted and weird, the front face is culled instead of the ones i'm not meant to see. This issue is probably not to do with my quaternion, matrix or vector classes as I copied them from github (as well as following the youtube series connected to them).

to move left or right I use:

```
public void input(){
        float movAmt = (float)(10 * Time.getDelta());
        float rotAmt = (float)(100 * Time.getDelta());

        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_W)){
            move(getForward(), movAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_S)){
            move(getForward(), -movAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_A)){
            move(getLeft(), movAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_D)){
            move(getRight(), movAmt);
        }

        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_UP)){
            rotateX(-rotAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_DOWN)){
            rotateX(rotAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_LEFT)){
            rotateY(-rotAmt);
        }
        if(Input.getKey(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){
            rotateY(rotAmt);
        }
    }

    public void move(Vector3f dir, float amt){
        pos = pos.add(dir.mult(amt));
    }

    public void rotateY(float angle){
        Vector3f Haxis = yAxis.cross(forward);
        Haxis.normalize();

        forward.rotate(angle, yAxis);
        forward.normalize();

        up = forward.cross(Haxis);
        up.normalize();
    }

    public void rotateX(float angle){
        Vector3f Haxis = yAxis.cross(forward);
        Haxis.normalize();

        forward.rotate(angle, Haxis);
        forward.normalize();

        up = forward.cross(Haxis);
        up.normalize();
    }

    public Vector3f getLeft(){
        return forward.cross(up).normalize();
    }

    public Vector3f getRight(){
        return up.cross(forward).normalize();
    }
```

Where should I look to find the issue? (In general throughout the whole program)

Comment: Why are you scaling by a negative number? If you want to make it smaller, use a number < 1 but > 0.

Comment: That's not the point, it should just be flipped around and not culled weird, my main problem is movement on x an y though.

Comment: That code seems ok, I'm assuming pos is taken into account by the rendering in parts of the code you haven't posted. That it is some kind of global variable or a member. Same for forward and up? It sounds weird to me that normalize() normalizes the vector as well as returning it. Make sure it does the right thing ( usually there are two methods to normalize vectors : normalize and normalizeSelf )

Comment: Well my normalize() code simply takes each part of the vector, divides it by itself and returns the result vector.

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code when I get back to the PC, sorry if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: @SamWalls that is the point. Scaling by a negative value will change which face is the backface, which is what culling uses.

Comment: @SamWalls to normalize a vector you want to divide each component by the length of the vector. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kinda confusing to me, as I think you're talking about two things.

But when you scale with a negative value like `glScalef(1f, -1f, 1f);` then you need to invert the [front face](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) using `glFrontFace();`

Example:

```
// Render stuff

glPushMatrix();
glFrontFace(GL_CW);

// Render negatively scaled stuff

glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glPopMatrix();

// Render stuff
```

*Note: I'm only using the deprecated methods for show, so if you've created your own matrix stack then you can simply change my example to fit your code.*